# Canvas API - Draw a line twice leads to different color - Fill a text twice leads to "bold" font

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I develop a web application where a user can move objects around... meaning that during mouseMove events I have to redraw the canvas. To do this efficiently, I only invoke clearRect() at the locations where something changed, e.g. at the old object location where the object to be moved was, and at the new one. This works fine.

But what I experienced is that outside of these two cleared rectangles, things changed (slightly) during mouseMove (IMHO nothing should be changed outside the cleared rectangles). I dig into it and it lead to something which I think is weird, but which happens in multiple browsers so it seems not to be a browser bug.

To draw a line, you can do this:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(74,12,95,1)';
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
const p1 = new Path2D();
p1.moveTo(posNumSummits, 0);
p1.lineTo(posNumSummits, this.CANVAS_TOP_PX - 2);
p1.lineTo(posNumSummits + numSummitsTextLen.width + textMargin + 10, this.CANVAS_TOP_PX - 2);
ctx.stroke(p1);
```

This works perfectly well, and draws the line in the correct color. But when I just repeat the same stroke again, the line gets a different color:

```
ctx.stroke(p1);
ctx.stroke(p1);
```

I made sure that globalAlpha is 1, and that the color used is not transparent (I would understand the behavior if the color were transparent).

The same happens when I invoke fillText():

```
ctx.fillText(numSummitsText, posNumSummits + textMargin, this.CANVAS_TOP_PX - 18);
```

Calling fillText once works perfectly well, but calling it twice like this:

```
ctx.fillText(numSummitsText, posNumSummits + textMargin, this.CANVAS_TOP_PX - 18);
ctx.fillText(numSummitsText, posNumSummits + textMargin, this.CANVAS_TOP_PX - 18);
```

leads to the same displayed text obviously, but the text looks boldish (like it was written twice at the same location, but slightly moved).

Now the questions:

- Why does the same paint-action in a canvas lead to a different canvas image?
- Is it wasted effort to try to be as efficient as possible and only use clearRect() where something changed. Should I clear the whole canvas every time?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is called [antialiasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing). To smooth the drawings of lines that would not fall perfectly on a pixel's boundaries, transparency will be added to this pixel. Drawing twice at the same position will add more opacity.
2. Yes it may even be worst in terms of performances to clear only a part of the context, and it will definitely make your code cleaner to clear all and redraw all every frame.